# How to install VMWare vCenter Converter plugin without internet?

Tags: vmware-converter

I have a standalone (no internet connection) vCenter with some ESX hosts. And I want to install plug-in VMWare Converter (not a standaone version). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't terribly clear so I'm going to have to make some assumptions here - let me know if they're wrong.

Basically you'd normally install Converter from the same CD/DVD/ISO that you installed vCenter from, it's just one of the other options in the autoplay menu - you just point it to your VC and away you go. Once that's running you have to choose 'Plugins'/'Manage Plugins' from any CS/VIclient - click on Converter from the available plug-ins menu and follow your nose from there. Depending on which version of the client you have you may have to enable to plug-in once it's installed and you may even have to restart the client too but that should be it.

Hope this helps.